# How do I make two shortcode use the same id and increment it when I use them multiple times?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, shortcode

I have created two shortcodes: one for the tabs, the second one for the tab panes:

```
[tab target="123"]Tab 1[/tab]
[tab-pane id="123"]Tabe pane 1[/tab]
```

Shortcodes:

```
function tab($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "target" => ''
    ), $atts));
    return '<ul class="nav nav-tab"><li><a href="#' . $target . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $content . '</a></li></ul>';
}
add_shortcode('tab', 'tab');

function tab-pane($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "id" => ''
    ), $atts));
    return '<div class="tab-content"><div id="#' . $id. '" class="tab-pane">' . $content . '</a></div>';
}
add_shortcode('tab-pane', 'tab-pane');
```

The above is based on the standard Bootstrap tabs behaviour, so I need a `target` and an `id` to make it work.

However, I don't want users to bother about unique targets / ids and want to generate it automatically for the two shortcodes (so I want to get rid of the target / id attributes to make it easier for users to create tab / tab pane pair). I could have just created a variable for them to share, however I want to make sure the whole thing works for multiple instances of the tab / tab pane pairs.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me after reading it 2 times. Can you please add a valid example of what you want/tried?

Comment: @JackJohansson, sorry for my English. I have added two examples for the shortcodes implementation. The result is just a standard Bootstrap tab block: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: I think shortcodes like this won't bring you far. Look at how sliders deal with a similar issue: You could create a custom post type where title and content represent tab name and tab pane. Combine those posts (eg via another CPT), and finally include them in your page/post via one shortcode

Comment: @kero, you've just open my eyes. Not only on how I should organize the tabs, but the whole theme customization in general. Thanks you!